# Dapr can't find address for .Net actor

Tags: .net, dapr

Dapr can't find the address for the actor when following the tutorial [How to: Run and use virtual actors in the .NET SDK](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/sdks/dotnet/dotnet-actors/dotnet-actors-howto/)

Dapr version

```
PS D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActorService> dapr --version
CLI version: 1.9.1 
Runtime version: 1.9.3
```

Dapr Actor output

```
PS D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActorService> dapr run --app-id myapp --app-port 5000 --dapr-http-port 3500 -- dotnet run
Starting Dapr with id myapp. HTTP Port: 3500. gRPC Port: 43602
== APP == Building...
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.7973578+01:00" level=info msg="starting Dapr Runtime -- version 1.9.3 -- commit 549b240ea0105feebf0b90b36e5564280eb81066" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.7978873+01:00" level=info msg="log level set to: info" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.7978873+01:00" level=info msg="metrics server started on :43603/" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.metrics type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8007135+01:00" level=info msg="standalone mode configured" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8007135+01:00" level=info msg="app id: myapp" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8012439+01:00" level=info msg="mTLS is disabled. Skipping certificate request and tls validation" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8018353+01:00" level=info msg="Dapr trace sampler initialized: DaprTraceSampler(P=1.000000)" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8737978+01:00" level=info msg="local service entry announced: myapp -> 192.168.50.43:43604" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.contrib type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8737978+01:00" level=info msg="Initialized name resolution to mdns" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8737978+01:00" level=info msg="loading components" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8867956+01:00" level=info msg="component loaded. name: pubsub, type: pubsub.redis/v1" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8873279+01:00" level=info msg="waiting for all outstanding components to be processed" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8927089+01:00" level=info msg="detected actor state store: statestore" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8931509+01:00" level=info msg="component loaded. name: statestore, type: state.redis/v1" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8937095+01:00" level=info msg="all outstanding components processed" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8942671+01:00" level=info msg="gRPC proxy enabled" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8947756+01:00" level=info msg="enabled gRPC tracing middleware" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.api type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8953011+01:00" level=info msg="enabled gRPC metrics middleware" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.api type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8953011+01:00" level=info msg="API gRPC server is running on port 43602" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.896382+01:00" level=info msg="enabled metrics http middleware" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.http type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8971326+01:00" level=info msg="enabled tracing http middleware" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.http type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8976633+01:00" level=info msg="http server is running on port 3500" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8981932+01:00" level=info msg="The request body size parameter is: 4" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8987277+01:00" level=info msg="enabled gRPC tracing middleware" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.internal type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8987277+01:00" level=info msg="enabled gRPC metrics middleware" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.internal type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8992508+01:00" level=info msg="internal gRPC server is running on port 43604" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:02.8997847+01:00" level=info msg="application protocol: http. waiting on port 5000.  This will block until the app is listening on that port." app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
Updating metadata for app command: dotnet run
You're up and running! Both Dapr and your app logs will appear here.

== APP == D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActor.Interfaces\MyData.cs(7,23): warning CS8618: Non-nullable property 'PropertyA' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable. [D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActor.Interfaces\MyActor.Interfaces.csproj]
== APP == D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActor.Interfaces\MyData.cs(8,23): warning CS8618: Non-nullable property 'PropertyB' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable. [D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActor.Interfaces\MyActor.Interfaces.csproj]
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
== APP ==       Now listening on: https://localhost:5000
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
== APP ==       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
== APP ==       Hosting environment: Development
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
== APP ==       Content root path: D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActorService\
time="2022-11-19T10:05:06.6200854+01:00" level=info msg="application discovered on port 5000" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:06.6531356+01:00" level=info msg="actor runtime started. actor idle timeout: 1h0m0s. actor scan interval: 30s" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.actor type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:06.6827958+01:00" level=info msg="placement tables updated, version: 0" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime.actor.internal.placement type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:08.8627382+01:00" level=error msg="error occurred while beginning pubsub pubsub: the server closed connection before returning the first response byte. Make sure the server returns 'Connection: close' response header before closing the connection" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
time="2022-11-19T10:05:08.8633092+01:00" level=info msg="dapr initialized. Status: Running. Init Elapsed 6062ms" app_id=myapp instance=XPS15-Cloud scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.9.3
```

The output says there's an error with the pubsub but then it says that status is running, hence I don't know if this might be the problem or just something unrelated.

**Dapr Client**

```
PS D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActorClient> dotnet run
Startup up...
Calling SetDataAsync on MyActor:1...
Unhandled exception. Dapr.DaprApiException: error invoke actor method: error finding address for actor type MyActor with id 1
   at Dapr.Actors.DaprHttpInteractor.SendAsyncHandleUnsuccessfulResponse(Func`1 requestFunc, String relativeUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.Actors.DaprHttpInteractor.SendAsync(Func`1 requestFunc, String relativeUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.Actors.DaprHttpInteractor.InvokeActorMethodWithRemotingAsync(ActorMessageSerializersManager serializersManager, IActorRequestMessage remotingRequestRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.Actors.Communication.Client.ActorRemotingClient.InvokeAsync(IActorRequestMessage remotingRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.Actors.Client.ActorProxy.InvokeMethodAsync(Int32 interfaceId, Int32 methodId, String methodName, IActorRequestMessageBody requestMsgBodyValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.Actors.Client.ActorProxy.ContinueWithResult[TRetval](Int32 interfaceId, Int32 methodId, Task`1 task)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\source\repos\Dapr.Actor.Example\MyActorClient\Program.cs:line 21
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

I can't find any information how to troubleshoot it.